# Taking all the bandwidth

Tags: internet, bandwidth

Hi i'm curretly using ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I'm wondering how to take all my internet bandwidth.
i'm wondering how to use THIS(http://www.ecloudbuzz.com/use-full-bandwidth-of-internet-connection/) method on ubuntu. I do not want to go over with administrator thing(logging in with my local ip and such...).

Comment: What do you mean by 'take all my internet bandwidth'?  Do you mean consume all the bandwidth and then be able to use full speed?

Comment: Bandwidth varies based on your wireless card and application needs. Those are much bigger issues than trying to stop Ubuntu from updating/using your bandwidth (for a short period) in the background. Ubuntu will make maximal use of your bandwidth when it needs to.

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't explained it clearly... The reason why I am doing this is to get higher internet connection when playing games on ubuntu.

I found out this thread... Does this even work? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871477

yes Thomas Ward, that's what I meant :)
and Patrick Negus, I don't use wireless card, I use ethernet. I think why i'm misunderstanding is because I don't know anything about internet ;-;

Comment: Also, when I turn my xbox one on, it starts downloading, and I can barly use my internet, because my xbox one takes all the internet. I'm asking you how to do that on my ubuntu pc.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no such thing as reserved system bandwidth on Ubuntu as the thing you describe for Windows. If both your computer and your Xbox demand bandwidth and the Xbox gets preferred, that's a router configuration, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you saying that it isn't possible to do that on ubuntu? What an answer

Comment: Ubuntu provides all available bandwidth to your application. If an application still gets less than the bandwidth you have bought, that means either that your ISP is providing less than they write on your bill, that other devices in your network or other applications on the same system also request bandwidth, or that the server you connect to offers a smaller upstream bandwidth than you have available as downstream. The first and last options are not changeable by you. What you can do is to make sure that there are no other devices in the network and no other bandwith consuming applications.

Comment: But again, if there are multiple devices, the amount of bandwith they get in relation to each other depends not on the device itself but on your router configuration. The router normally can set up different network priorities, you have e.g. realtime traffic with highest priority for things like internet tv and maybe your Xbox is also configured in the router to have a higher priority.

Comment: How do I make my pc as a high priority? I use wired connenction

Comment: Configuring your router is off topic for Ask Ubuntu. If you want something on Ubuntu to take all your bandwidth, then connect to some host that has much higher bandwidth than you have, and can saturate your network connection. I suggest you go rear about how network data transfer actually works, rather than asking for non-solutions to a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Well using my xbox one as an example, whenever I download a game from xbox one, it just automatically sets hisself as a highest priority, and other device has lower internet speed than xbox. Which explains you that xbox one can manage to get himself a high priority without my help who can access to the router. and my question was how to do that on my pc which has ubuntu installed. Xbox one can do it by himself, why can't I do it with ubuntu PC without touching modem or router?

Comment: Well, go download a 30GB file on Ubuntu and watch your bandwidth saturate. You can't compare downloading a single massive thing to general usage. Saturating your bandwidth is not a good thing and unlikely to solve whatever problem it is you think you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What matters for gaming is rarely bandwidth once you have a certain amount of it, and unless you're running bittorrent or something in the background which is designed to consume lots of bandwidth. Normal checking for available updates won't generally cause problems, as it doesn't take all the bandwidth, and doesn't affect latency.

If you're playing a game on a poor server, with horrible latency, it doesn't really matter how much bandwidth you have. I have 500 Mbps upstream connection, and still some on-line games are very laggy.

Comment: I want it like 1ms. and i'm playing on pretty good servers :) I saw someone getting 1ms

Comment: Also, when I turn my xbox one on, it starts downloading, and I can barly use my internet, because my xbox one takes all the internet. I'm asking you how to do that on my ubuntu pc.

Comment: A ping of 1ms is utopic on the internet unless maybe if you're directly in the neighbourhood of an internet node and the target server. That was likely a ping time inside a small LAN only. A more realistic ping time is 20-50ms on the internet.

Comment: What do you mean by "small LAN only"?

Comment: You're only going to get 1ms on local network. Getting 1ms on Internet is extremely unlikely. The best I've gotten on https://beta.speedtest.net is 3ms, and that's to a ~local (within 50 miles) test host, and i have fiber straight to my house. If you want fast Internet access, you're probably going to have to pay for it. No number of tricks on your local PC are going to fix whatever "slowness" you are seeing.

Comment: okay that makes sense to me. But sometimes, when I do test on beta.speedtest.net, I sometimes get low ping and sometimes very high ping. Is there a way to stablize it or like make it stay low?

Comment: The ping time on speedtest is not the ping you will get when talking to any server on the Internet. It is the ping time to the test server, at the time of the test. If you want it stable, then always ensure you use the same test server.

Comment: Even though I use the same test server, when I'm on a "minecraft" game, and see my ping, it always changes. and I'm asking you if it's possible to stablize it so it won't change it 20 ms to like 500 ms.

Comment: No, the ping time has basically nothing to do with the software.